# j2me+choice group

Tags: java-me

I am working on the project where i had used choice group in form. Now I want to get the selected item or index number of the choice group and want to perform some action.

I had tried through this:-

`System.out.println(cgPrefs.getString(i) + (selected[i] ? ": selected" : ": not selected"))`;

But I am not getting the exact index number of the selected item in choice group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get flags according to selection

```
boolean[] selectedFlag = new boolean[getChoiceGroup().size()];
```

using `getSelectedFlags()` method

```
getChoiceGroup().getSelectedFlags(selectedFlag);//getChoiceGroup() returns object of choicegroup
```

Now iterate and print

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < selectedFlag.length; i ++){
  if(selectedFlag[i]){
    System.out.println("Selected : "+getChoiceGroup().getString(i));
  }else{
    System.out.println("Not Selected : "+getChoiceGroup().getString(i));
  }
}
```